# How to create a text editor in with line numbers in a web app

Tags: css, html, firefox-os

I'm trying to create a text editor with line numbers, which increments with the lines increase. Well, my focus is to make the UI that will do good in Firefox OS as a privilege app. But in UI what css and html need to be used to create a text-field where line numbers must not be editable by the user. And few other thing say like, text-field is fixed height `height: 100px;` now if text overflows and if the user scroll then line numbers must scroll together with respective lines. (I'm trying to create with `textarea` and `div` with `contenteditable="true"`). I'm not able to scroll the text-field if I [try this](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/examples/example-hook-linenums.html).  Please provide some help or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone who has worked on this problem for over a year at a previous company. Just use one of the existing source code editors like [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/) or [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/). They'll work in a Firefox OS app as well (f.e. Cloud9 IDE uses Ace and works on FFOS).

Comment: CodeMirror is awesome. Thank you so very much for suggesting this. I like how w3schools has their code examples done but was not a fan of all the lengthy code used. The CodeMirror simplifies and makes it easy to implement. 
Thank you, Jan.
Wayne